# Clarifying Javascript Object.defineProperties usage

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I still don't feel like I completely understand the use of Object.defineProperties, so I'd appreciate some input on the following (somewhat contrived) examples:

---

### 1. `my_val` behaves the same for `one` and `two` in the following code:

```
var Class_1 = function (arg) {
    this.my_val = arg;
};

var Class_2 = function (arg) {
    Object.defineProperties(this,{
        my_val : {
            value : arg,
            writable : true,
            enumerable : true,
            configurable : true
        }
    });
};

var one = new Class_1("foo");
var two = new Class_2("foo");
```

And the reasoning for using `defineProperties` over just assigning it like in Class_1 would be when you want `writable`, `enumerable` or `configurable` to be false; Basically it's for control. Otherwise the simple `this.property` definition is identical, correct?

---

### 2. `my_val` behaves the same for `three` and `four` in the following code:

```
var Class_value = function (arg) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        my_val : {
            value : arg, 
            writable : true,
//          enumerable : false   // default
//          configurable : false // default
        }
    });
};

var Class_getSet = function (arg) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        __my_val : {
            value : arg,
            writable : true,
//          enumerable : false   // default
//          configurable : false // default
        },
        my_val : {
            get : function(){ return this.__my_val; }, 
            set : function(new_val){ this.__my_val = new_val; }
        }
    });
};

var three = new Class_value("foo");
var four = new Class_getSet("foo");
```

And the reasoning for using `get`/`set` functions over just `value` would be when you want to add more advanced logic, like calling another function when `my_val` is updated, or sending an event, etc. Also you cannot use `get`/`set` without at least defining the initial value (either via a `value` property shown here, or via the simple `this.property = ...` definition as in **1.**), correct?

---

Basically I'm just looking to make sure that I understand the reasoning for how and when to use defineProperties, since I feel like I don't have a good handle on the concept yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my_val behaves the same for one and two

Yes.

> my_val behaves the same for three and four

No - there's `__my_val`. You might at least consider using a local-scoped, "private" variable instead of a public property.

> And the reasoning for using get/set functions over just value would be when you want to add more advanced logic, like calling another function when my_val is updated, or sending an event, etc.

Yes, that's what [getters/setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getter/setter) are made for.

> Also you cannot use get/set without at least defining the initial value (either via a value property shown here, or via the simple this.property = ... definition as in 1.), correct?

No, you could simply leave it `undefined` as well.

Comment: Ah ok, getting all worked up about properties I forgot about simple private variables. So in the case of **2.** I could instead have something like this: https://gist.github.com/CarnotInteractive/47bd2de33c88125299a8 which would behave the same for anyone using `three` and `four`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should exhibit the same behaviour.