# How do I implement an EvenEmitter in my own JavaScript class (function)?

Tags: javascript, events

I like node-like evented programming model. Does anyone know how could I implement Events in my own JavaScript browser code? Here's an example:

```
function Person () { // Person is an even emitter;
   this.goToWork = function () { 
     this.emit('moved', 100, 100); // work is at 100, 100
   }
}

var person = new Person();
person.goToWork();

person.on('moved', function (x, y) {
  console.log('person moved to ${x} ${y}');
});
```

Any ideas how to make my own class `Person` be an event emitter in browsers? Does anyone have skeleton class or example code for making event emitters?

Comment: Does [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12341715/451969)?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help.

Comment: Is that to say then that dispatching a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) isn't the same as "emitting" an event in the way you're describing? Can you elaborate?

Comment: node->emit uses an underlying socket connection, how could you do this in the browser without considerable work?

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Your answer wasn't helpful, sorry. I'm trying to implement node like EventEmitter but your answer is something different. That's why I downvoted it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm looking to add an EventEmitter like interface to my class. Your answer is a bit different. I apologize about misunderstanding, I've upvoted your answer now.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I was unable to upvote your answer completely back unfortunately. There is a timeout mechanism that disallows to change my vote after certain time. I apologize about misunderstanding.

Comment: I hacked the system - I edited it myself and as a result I could change my vote. Thanks for helping! @JaredFarrish

Comment: There's [this](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter). This looks familiar: `function Player(){}; Player.prototype = Object.clone(EventEmitter.prototype);` I don't follow the difference between event emitting and basic event dispatching, so I am probably not much help. And thanks for fixing the vote.

Comment: @JaredFarrish "And thanks for fixing the vote." --- how to make people happy: make them feeling worse then revert it back :-D

Comment: If you check the [guide](https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter/blob/master/docs/guide.md#method-aliases) of that project I linked, it looks like that's what you're asking for here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarifying Javascript Object.defineProperties usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886361/clarifying-javascript-object-defineproperties-usage)